# June 2012 Moderator Election: Town Hall Chat - Wednesday at 19:00:00Z UTC / 3:00 PM EDT

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we will be holding a Town Hall Chat session with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.  Rebecca is out for a bit, so it will be I that will be working with the candidates to find a time that allows the most participation.

***The Town Hall Chat took place Wednesday the 13th at 19:00:00Z UTC. A digest version of the event can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136099/june-2012-moderator-election-town-hall-chat-digest).***

---

Here are the details so far:

- I would like to schedule this towards the beginning of the primary phase.  This means that I am looking around June 11th-13th. As soon as I coordinate with the existing moderators and candidates to find a best fit based on availability, this post shall be edited with details on the "when".
- The Town Hall Chat will be a one-hour event using our [chat platform](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/).  I will update this post with a direct link to the chat room once the event is scheduled.
- The format will be an open discussion.  Users are encouraged to pose questions to the candidates regarding their thoughts on moderation.
- After the chat session, a digest of the event will be permanently linked here.

Comment: Questions *will* be asked.  Be ready, candidates.

Comment: On stackoverflow, Positions available should be 5. I think moderators are overworking. Moderation responce is taking time currently.

Comment: @SomnathMuluk It's *always* going to take time.  We'd probably need an extra 20 moderators if you're expecting a snappier response time on flags.

Comment: I'll set my spam filter to `"stun"` ;)

Comment: Rebecca, go back to your account. We know you're back at work already.

Comment: And let me just [warn the candidates in advance...](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WWPuy.jpg)

Comment: @Grace: Will there be a second round again (for the candidates who missed this date)? Or alternatively would it be acceptoooble to have a static on-meta questionnaire to the nominees as well? (Less rushed, more light-hearted questions.)

Comment: @Grace :-( I wasnt able to make it.... I had an impromptu meeting at my office :-(